# Is is possible to recover from the unexpected removal of the root device?

Tags: linux, mount, root-filesystem, unmounting

Is it possible to recover from the entire removal and reinsertion of the root device (i.e. remounting it after reinsertion)?

I'm attempting to teach a group of children about Linux via external USB drives, and I'm worried one of them may unplug a drive out of curiosity.

I would assume not, due to the loss of /dev, but I decided to ask anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, no.  The system will panic once the root device disappears. You can verify this in your particular situation if you want using a virtualization application like VirtualBox, qemu, kvm, etc.  These will allow you to remove a virtual HDD from the machine and observe the result on the system.

If you're interested in making a bootable USB drive that loads into RAM and runs from there, check out [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/) and its variants and clones or any of the Live Linux distributions.  Once it boots, the source medium can be removed.  Its original purpose was to have a fully functioning system on CD/DVD but it works well from USB also.

Comment: Thanks. I had heard something about running an image of a distro entirely in ram, but I never looked into it. Though those distros do seem rather interesting, I decided on using my laptop as a server with an Ubuntu image to network boot the machines we will be using.